# Database page-level restore seemingly ineffective

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-administration

**Background**

SQL Server Enterprise 2012
Disk IO errors have occurred, causing two table errors:

```
DBCC CHECKDB(dbname)
GO
--Output:
--Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 1
--Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 0 (type Unknown), page (3:7432269). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 133129 and -6.
--Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 1
--Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 0 (type Unknown), page (3:7434265). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 133129 and -6.
```

The faulty disk has been replaced, with all files successfully copied to the replacement disk.

**Problem**

Having replaced the disk, subsequently carrying out a page-level restore from a full backup fortunately taken one day before the errors occurred results in 0 pages processed:

```
USE MASTER  
RESTORE DATABASE dbname PAGE = '3:7434265, 3:7432269' FROM DISK = 'P:\MSSQL_BACKUPS\dbname\dbname\dbname_backup_2016_02_27_050001_8076562.full.bak' WITH NORECOVERY
GO
--Output:
--Processed 0 pages for database 'dbname', file 'dbname_pt0b' on file 1.
--RESTORE DATABASE ... FILE=<name> successfully processed 0 pages in 398.710 seconds (0.000 MB/sec).
```

Running CHECKDB again confirms the errors are still present. As far as I'm aware this is the correct method to recover from database corruption where only a small number of pages are affected. I know this won't get me to a stage where the database is fully restored - I need to restore the subsequent logs for that - but it should at least be in a state where the table errors have been fixed. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Check about `DBCC CHECKDB([test], REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)`

Comment: @Devart - I don't want to risk losing any data if I can avoid it. Is the [test] part above actually a thing or are you just using it as a placeholder for the DB name? I can't find any reference to any kind of 'test' parameter in documentation